# Removing unwanted symbols/gremlins in HTML

Tags: html, css, notepad++

I am using notepad++ to make my website and every time I view it in a web browser gremlins show up. They show up in place of " and ' and some other symbols. I am using UTF-8 encoding, and have ried changing font.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Where does this content comes from? Database, PHP string, JSON, raw HTML? What does DevTools/Firebug say about the encoding of the HTML page received? How is set N++ when you open relevant files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add this line in your head section

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use special character entries. For example, you would write `&quot;` to get a " symbol. Use `&apos;` to get the ' symbol.

Here is a website you can use...
[HTML Characters](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: It is not a good solution to manually change all these characters. The problem here is more about encoding than escaping

Answer (score 1):

One cause for this can be the encoding you're using in Notepad++. You can change the encoding from the "Encoding" menu on the main menu bar. I'd suggest trying UTF-8 or UTF-8-BOM. You will need to resave and reupload your file(s) after making that change.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work I converted then saved but when ran displays the same thing.